# How do I regain access to root after accidental chsh command that went bad?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, user-management, root

I did a silly silly thing. While attempting to change the shell for user 'x' I was in a rush and did not type the users name at the end of the command, so I ended up running this:

```
chsh /sbin/nologin
```

This seemed to have then changed the default shell for root, to one that does not exists, and hence root can nolonger log in. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a Linode VPS. Luckily, they give you a recovery console to boot into, from there you can mount your **/dev/xdva** to a location and edit the files. These are the steps I followed:

- Logged into recovery mounted
- /dev/xvda to /media/xvda and cd to
- /media/xvda/ Edited /etc/passwd and
- changed roots shell back to /bin/bash
- Added user 'onestp' to the sudoers
- list, as a fallback account for me

Now, I still cannot log into the VPS via SSH as root, it says access denied. I have tried to change the password but still no access. I can however log in as user onestp, but even when I **sudo su -s /bin/bash root** I still get the error message that the directory **/sbin/nologin** does not exists, even through I just changed the shell for root back to /bin/bash!

I can confirm that the shell is correct by typing **sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep root** which the outputs this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue, I am at my whits end, have spent AGES configuring apache as a web server with php, mysql etc and reeeeealy do not want to rebuild.

For the record, I did not make a full image backup before this, no. Silly silly me!

Comment: Did you try sudo -i ?

Comment: @jscott I tried pretty much evry trick in the book, and I only just realized that I was not running my commands relative to the /media/xvda location but rather as / and therefore all my edits were relative on the RECOVERY IMAGE and not my mounted location. Silly silly error. But solved.

Answer (score 1):

@All,

This was a silly mistake, but I have solved it. When booting up with the recovery image for the VPS, I had to mount my **/dev/xvda** to **/media/xvda** however when running commands such as **sudo nano /etc/passwd** they were running relative to the RECOVERY IMAGE and not my mounted location.

Simply running sudo nano etc/passwd sorted this whle mess out because now I was editing **/meda/xvda/etc/passwd** instead of **[RECOVERY IAMGE]/etc/passwd**

I change the shell back to /bin/bash for root and SSH access was restored.

I hope someone can take something away with them from this silly mistake of mine.